# I cant get hive to run jobs with spark

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, hive

Running hive with spark keeps giving me this error. I have tried many different versions of both hive and spark.

Running hadoop 2.7.3 in standalone mode 
it is a diy implementation 
right now using spark 2.2 with hive 2.3.5

I tried different versions of hive and spark, I am not sure what exactly the problem is or how to debug this:

```
0: jdbc:hive2://192.168.71.62:10000> select count(*) from traffic;
    Getting log thread is interrupted, since query is done!
    Error: org.apache.hive.service.cli.HiveSQLException: Error while processing statement: FAILED: Execution Error, return code 1 from org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.SparkTask. Failed to create spark client.
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.Operation.toSQLException(Operation.java:380)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:257)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
    Caused by: org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.metadata.HiveException: Failed to create spark client.
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionImpl.open(SparkSessionImpl.java:64)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionManagerImpl.getSession(SparkSessionManagerImpl.java:115)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.runInternal(Driver.java:1526)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1237)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.Driver.run(Driver.java:1232)
        at org.apache.hive.service.cli.operation.SQLOperation.runQuery(SQLOperation.java:255)
        ... 11 more
        Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: Cancel client '9be4c047-285d-4578-a934-7bd51294d240'. Error: Child process exited before connecting back with error log Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: hive.spark.client.server.connect.timeout=90000
        Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: hive.spark.client.rpc.threads=8
        Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: hive.spark.client.connect.timeout=1000
        Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: hive.spark.client.secret.bits=256
        Warning: Ignoring non-spark config property: hive.spark.client.rpc.max.size=52428800
        19/05/20 12:39:42 WARN util.Utils: Your hostname, suypc183-OptiPlex-3020 resolves to a loopback address: 127.0.0.1; using 192.168.71.62 instead (on interface enp2s0)
        19/05/20 12:39:42 WARN util.Utils: Set SPARK_LOCAL_IP if you need to bind to another address
        19/05/20 12:39:43 INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
        19/05/20 12:39:43 INFO yarn.Client: Requesting a new application from cluster with 1 NodeManagers
        19/05/20 12:39:43 INFO yarn.Client: Verifying our application has not requested more than the maximum memory capability of the cluster (8192 MB per container)
        19/05/20 12:39:43 INFO yarn.Client: Will allocate AM container, with 1408 MB memory including 384 MB overhead
        19/05/20 12:39:43 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up container launch context for our AM
        19/05/20 12:39:43 INFO yarn.Client: Setting up the launch environment for our AM container
        19/05/20 12:39:43 INFO yarn.Client: Preparing resources for our AM container
        19/05/20 12:39:44 INFO yarn.Client: Deleted staging directory hdfs://localhost:9000/user/anonymous/.sparkStaging/application_1558334426394_0004
        Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Can not create a Path from an empty string
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.checkPathArg(Path.java:126)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:134)
            at org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path.<init>(Path.java:93)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.copyFileToRemote(Client.scala:369)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$Client$$distribute$1(Client.scala:490)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.prepareLocalResources(Client.scala:529)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.createContainerLaunchContext(Client.scala:882)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.submitApplication(Client.scala:171)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.run(Client.scala:1167)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client$.main(Client.scala:1226)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.Client.main(Client.scala)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.org$apache$spark$deploy$SparkSubmit$$runMain(SparkSubmit.scala:744)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$1.run(SparkSubmit.scala:169)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$$anon$1.run(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
            at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
            at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
            at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1698)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.doRunMain$1(SparkSubmit.scala:167)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.submit(SparkSubmit.scala:212)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit$.main(SparkSubmit.scala:126)
            at org.apache.spark.deploy.SparkSubmit.main(SparkSubmit.scala)

            at com.google.common.base.Throwables.propagate(Throwables.java:160)
            at org.apache.hive.spark.client.SparkClientImpl.<init>(SparkClientImpl.java:125)
            at org.apache.hive.spark.client.SparkClientFactory.createClient(SparkClientFactory.java:80)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.RemoteHiveSparkClient.createRemoteClient(RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:101)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.RemoteHiveSparkClient.<init>(RemoteHiveSparkClient.java:97)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.HiveSparkClientFactory.createHiveSparkClient(HiveSparkClientFactory.java:73)
            at org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.exec.spark.session.SparkSessionImpl.open(SparkSessionImpl.java:62)
            ... 22 more
```

hive site configs are the following

```
  <property>
    <name>hive.exec.scratchdir</name>
    <value>/tmp/hive</value>
    <description>Scratch space for Hive jobs</description>
  </property>
  <property>
  <name>hive.execution.engine</name>
  <value>spark</value>
</property>
  <property>
      <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
   <property>
      <name>spark.master</name>
      <value>yarn</value>
   </property>
    <property>
      <name>spark.executor.memory</name>
      <value>2048</value>
  </property>
      <property>
      <name>spark.yarn.archive</name>
      <value>hdfs://localhost:8088/user/jars/</value> 
  </property>
        <property>
      <name>spark.home</name>
      <value>/home/danielphingston/spark</value>
  </property>
```

Comment: Probably you need to provide a bit more information about your configuration. For example, is it a DIY implementation, or are using a standard distribution from Hortonworks or Cloudera etc?

Answer (score 0):

The most typical problem of connection between Hive and Spark is making sure that Spark knows the HADOOP CONF DIRECTORY. We solve that by provide below statements in the spark-env.sh file within Spark:

```
HADOOP_CONF_DIR=${HADOOP_CONF_DIR:-$SPARK_CONF_DIR/yarn-conf}
HIVE_CONF_DIR=${HIVE_CONF_DIR:-/etc/hive/conf}
if [ -d "$HIVE_CONF_DIR" ]; then
  HADOOP_CONF_DIR="$HADOOP_CONF_DIR:$HIVE_CONF_DIR"
fi
export HADOOP_CONF_DIR
```

This enables Spark to see where Hadoop directories are present in the file system.